# My code stops running after it takes first input of scanf

Tags: c, pointers

I have to write a code using ONLY 2D pointers, and it should include functions to allocate: a 1D array, an array of arrays, and a 2D array. However in a function to read the arrays, it stops after first input of scanf

In the function "info" (where the problem is) I tried changing it to ((A+i)+j), (*(A+I)+j) and *(*(A+i)+j). None worked.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
.
.
.
void allocate1(float *A, int N)
  {
    A=(float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float*));
  }
void allocate2(float **A, int N)
   {
     A=(float**)malloc(N*sizeof(float**));
   }
void allocate(float **A, int M, int N)
   {
      int i;
      allocate2(A,M);
      for(i=0;i<M;i++)
      allocate1(*(A+i),N);
   }
  void info(float **A, int N, int M)
    {
      int i,j;
      for(i=0;i<M;i++)
      for(j=0;j<N;j++)
       {
         printf("input element (%d,%d)\n", i+1,j+1);
         scanf("%f",(*(A+i)+j));
       }
     }
     .
     .
     .
     void main()
      {
        float **A,**B,**C;
         int N,M,P,D;
        do
          {
            M=read();
            N=read();
            D=read();
            P=read();
          }while(D!=N);
         allocate(A,M,N);
         allocate(B,N,P);
         info(A,N,M);
       .
       .
```

Answer (score 0):

The question does not specify the input. Most likely, it's something like '1.2 3.4' (or similar, may be with new line between the numbers).

Since the code is using '%f' to read each number, it will fail to skip over the space/newline (or whatever other separators exists). Consider adding leading ' ' to the scanf format to allow skipping over white spaces.

```
scanf(" %f", &a[i][j]).
```

No need to do pointer math - let the compiler do the hard job.

Side note, you want to add a check on scanf return code. If it's not 1, you want to exit, as this indicate EOF, or other parsing errors.  Currently, the code does not have have any recovery/error handling, better to fail fast.

Comment: I need to use the pointer notations in scanf. and in my input I use 1 or something like that